# Is subset of $L^1$ functions bounded by $1 / x^2$ compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, compactness, oscillatory-integral

I was given the following exercise

> Given $E \subset L^1([1, +\infty))$ as follows
> $$
> E = \left\{ f \in L^1([1, +\infty)) \;\middle|\; \forall x \in [1, +\infty) \quad |f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{x^2} \right\}
> $$
>
> - is $E$ bounded?
> - is $E$ closed?
> - is $E$ compact?

I tried solving it with other people. First we noticed that for $E$ to be well defined in $L^1$ the condition should actually be *for almost all* $x \in [1, +\infty)$ otherwise it is meaningless in $L^1$.

Then I was told that $E$ was compact and that there are various (non obvious) ways to prove it: one uses the fact that given $f_n(x)$ we can use [Lousin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) to get families of continuos functions that are then used to construct $f(x)$ over the rationals... Another one uses convolution of the $f_n$ with a smooth kernel to get a continuous function to define the limit $f(x)$... But after this we found that the sequence of functions given by
$$
f_n(x) = \left|\frac{\sin(nx)}{x^2}\right|
$$
is in $L^1$ as $\forall n \; \int_1^\infty |\sin(nx)/x^2| \mathrm dx \leq \int_1^\infty |1/x^2| \mathrm dx = \|1 / x^2\|_{L^1} < +\infty$ and $|f_n| \leq 1 /x^2$ so satisfies the condition but we could not find what this function should converge to in $E$, is this an actual counterexample and the statement is actually false or is there an explicit limit for this sequence?

**Note.** We got this exercise as a kind of extension of the analogous set in $\ell^1$ given by $\{ (x_n)_n \in \ell^1 \mid |x_n| \leq 1 / n^2 \}$.

Comment: Remember that if $X$ is compact it means every bounded sequence has a subsequence that converges, not that every bounded sequence converges.

Comment: I wonder how do you construct $f(x)$ by continuous functions. Arzela-Ascoli Theorem? You do have bounded condition. How about equi-continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*$E$ is bounded:* For all $u \in E$, $$ \| u\|_{L^1([1,\infty))}\leqslant \int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x^2} \, dx =1. $$

---

*$E$ is closed:* Let $\{u_k\} \subset E$ be a sequence of functions which converge in $L^1([1,\infty))$ to $u$. Then $$\vert u(x) \vert  \leqslant \vert u_k(x)-u(x) \vert +\vert u_k(x) \vert \leqslant \vert u_k(x)-u(x) \vert +\frac 1 {x^2} $$ for all $x\in [1,\infty)$. Since $u_k \to u$ in $L^1([1,\infty))$, $u_k \to u$ a.e. after passing to a subsequence (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018205/convergence-in-l1-implies-there-exists-a-subsequence-that-converges-almost-ev) for example). Hence, after passing to this subsequence then sending $k \to \infty$ we conclude that $$ \vert u(x) \vert \leqslant \frac 1 {x^2} \qquad \text{a.e.}$$

---

*E is not compact:* Let $v_k$ be the Rademacher functions (see [the first example here](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/notes/8-2.pdf)) except defined on $[1,2]$ instead of $[0,1]$ and set $u_k(x) = \frac 1 4 v_k \chi_{[1,2]}$. Then $$\vert u_k(x) \vert \leqslant\frac 1 4 \chi_{[1,2]} \leqslant \frac 1 {x^2}. $$ But $$\| u_k - u_\ell \|_{L^1([1,\infty))} =\frac1 4  $$ for all $k,\ell$ so $u_k$ do not have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I believe the distance between the two functions is ${1 \over 8}$ as I mentioned above.

Comment: Unless I'm making a computation error, I'm getting that $\| v_k - v_\ell \|_{L^1([1,2])} =1$ for all $k \neq\ell$ which would give $\| v_k - v_\ell \|_{L^1} =1/4$.

Comment: Actually, looking at your counter-example it can only take values $0,1$ while mine takes values $-1,1$ which is probably the discrepancy. That being said, I didn't realise how similar our examples were - I've never though of defined the Rademacher functions in terms of the binary expansion of $x$. Sorry about that

Answer (score 4):

We have $\|f\| \le \int_1^\infty {1 \over x^2} dx = 1$ hence $E$ is bounded.

It is straightforward to see that $E$ is convex, hence $E$ is closed **iff** $E$ is weakly closed.

Suppose $f_n \overset{w}{\to} f$ with $f_n \in E$. Suppose $f \notin E$ and let $A_m = \{ x | |f(x)| > {1 \over x^2} + { 1\over m} \}$, we see that the Lebesgue measure $\lambda A_m >0$ for some $m$. Let $\phi(x) = 1_{A_m}(x) \operatorname{sgn} f(x)$, note that $\phi \in L^\infty$ and
$\int \phi f = \int_{A_m} |f| \ge \int_{A_m} {1 \over x^2} dx + { 1\over m} \lambda A_m$. However, note that $\int \phi f_n \le \int_{A_m} {1 \over x^2} dx $ for all $n$ and so we obtain a contradiction. Hence $ f\in E$ and so $E$ is closed.

Let $f_n$ be zero everywhere except on $[1,2)$ where $f_n(x)$ is the $n$th digit of the binary expansion of $x-1$ multiplied by ${1 \over 4}$ (so it lies in $E$). Then the distance between any two distinct $f_n$s is ${ 1\over 8} $ and so cannot contain any convergent subsequence. Hence $E$ is not compact.

Comment: The interval is $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @podiki Crap, Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @podiki Thanks again for catching that, I believe I have repaired my answer.